# how to add days using Date without using Calendar

Tags: java, date

```
public XDate addDays(long a) {
    long x = super.getTime();
    a *= (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    Date dd = new Date(x + a);
    XDate d = new XDate(dd.getDate() + date - 1, dd.getMonth(), dd.getYear());
    return d;
}
```

so I made a class called XDate which extends java.util.Date but do things little different, for example, getMonth return a value from 1-12 and not 0-11,
now, I want to make a function called `addDays(int a)`, which basically uses the current date (the date can be edited in the constructor) and add the number a to the day's section, using `Date.getTime()` and the Date constructor that gets milliseconds.

Comment: Please provide some sample code and show us what is unclear.

Comment: Btw, redeclaring the return value of getMonth is a blatent violation of liskow's law.

Comment: I would seriously recommend you use `Calendar` instead of `Date`. Those methods of `Date` are deprecated since Java 1.1 (!). Apart from that, redeclaring the return value of `getMonth` like that is a blatant violation of Liskow's law.

Comment: Hope that doesn't go in production somewhere

Comment: If you use this in code that someone else will have to maintain, they or their successors will likely eventually rip this out and refactor all code that depends on it.  DO NOT DO THIS. Learn and use the existing java.time API instead.

Comment: @DorianGray - it is a principle ... not a law.

Comment: I recommend you neither use `Date` nor `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
)
.plusDays( 3 )
```

## java.time

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Never use `Date` again.

Apparently you are starting with a `long` as a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Parse that number as a `Instant`, a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myCountOfMilliseconds ) ;
```

When you say “add days”, what do you mean exactly?

Do you mean **24-hour chunks of time**? Use `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofDays( 3 ) ;  // Add three multiplied by 24 hours.
Instant instantLater = instant.plus( d ) ;
```

Do you mean **days as in dates** on the calendar? A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusDays( 3 ) ;  // Add three calendar days, with same time-of-day but adjusted as needed to handle anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).
```

If you want only the date without the time-of-day and without the time zone, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate ldLater = ld.plusDays( 3 ) ;
```

> bassicly uses the current date

If you wanted to start with the date-only, use `LocalDate.now`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate threeDaysFromToday = today.plusDays( 3 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `XDate` always represent the date and time with UTC timezone, you can simply add 86400000 to the internal time-value that represents milliseconds since epoch time (1970-01-01 00:00:00).

As soon as you want to work with dates representing dates and times of different timezones, you can't do that because there are days with 23 hours or days 25 hours if the timezone in question has daylight saving times. In that case you need to keep track of the dates when these changes occur and handle it accordingly.

Or you use `Calendar` instead.